# Почему textContent возвращает html теги?

Tags: javascript

```js
var gwgwgw=document.createElement('div');
gwgwgw.innerHTML='rgrdgrdr (&lt;a href="/page.php?addr=ine&amp;act=seaog&amp;q=%23zer" onclick="return nav.go(this,\'<a href="/search.php?act=blogs&amp;value=%23content" onclick="return nav.go(this,\'#content\');">#content</a>\');"&gt;<a href="/page.php?addr=ine&amp;act=seaog&amp;q=%23zer" onclick="return nav.go(this,\'#content\');">#zer@ine</a>&lt;/a&gt;)';
console.log(gwgwgw.textContent);
```

выводит:

```
rgrdgrdr (<a href="/page.php?addr=ine&act=seaog&q=%23zer" onclick="return nav.go(this,'#content');">#zer@ine</a>)
```

**Из комментариев**
Когда вставлял это, потом получалась ссылка.
Моей ошибкой было думать, что `textContent` очищает от html тегов

Comment: С чего Вы решили, что возращается **html**? Если вы про тэг **<a>**, то конечно он будет присутствовать, потому что Вы передали его как `&lt;`.

Comment: Не правильно вопрос сформулировал, да я про тэг <a>, когда вставлял это потом получалась ссылка, моей ошибкой было думать что textContent очищает от html тегов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте Ваш вопрос, что бы он стал праильным.

Answer (score 2):

`textContent` убирает теги, которые являются разметкой dom-элементов.

При этом возвращается текстовое содержимое, которое корректно в виде строки, но не html-разметки. Возвращаемая строка содержит непосредственно неэкранированный текст.

```
var d = document.createElement('div');

// html-разметка убирается
d.innerHTML = "123<b>456</b>789";
console.log(d.textContent); // 123456789

// тут не было html-разметки, мнемоники развёрнуты в код
d.innerHTML = "123&lt;b&gt;456&lt;/b&gt;789";
console.log(d.textContent); // 123<b>456</b>789

// тут тоже не было, html-разметка содержит мнемоники 
d.textContent = "123<b>456</b>789";
console.log(d.textContent); // 123<b>456</b>789
console.log(d.innerHTML);   // 123&lt;b&gt;456&lt;/b&gt;789
```

Answer (score -1):

Решение: использовать регулярку для очистки от тегов `.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/g,'')`